Unable to allocate memory for a Reinforcement Learning problem
import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.env_util import make_vec_env
from tqdm import tqdm
from TTset_main import load_TTset
import random

# Load the dataset
filted_tset_path = "path to training set"
filted_vset_path = "path to validation set"
TTset_training, TTset_vali, training_data_length = load_TTset(filted_tset_path, filted_vset_path)

# Custom Data Loader
def batch_loader(data, batch_size):
    """A generator function to load data in batches."""
    data_len = len(data)
    indices = np.arange(data_len)
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for start_idx in range(0, data_len, batch_size):
        excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batch_size]
        batch = [data[i] for i in excerpt]
        frames, labels = zip(*batch)
        frames = np.array(frames)
        labels = np.array(labels)
        yield frames, labels

# Custom Gym Environment
class VideoClassificationEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, ttset_training, batch_size):
        super(VideoClassificationEnv, self).__init__()
        self.ttset_training = ttset_training
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.current_batch = None
        self.current_index = 0
        self.current_video = 0
        
        # Assuming each element is of shape (3, 60, 230, 230)
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=255, 
                                            shape=(3, 60, 230, 230), dtype=np.uint8)
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(20)
        self.batch_gen = batch_loader(self.ttset_training, self.batch_size)

    def reset(self):
        self.current_index = 0
        try:
            self.current_batch, self.current_labels = next(self.batch_gen)
        except StopIteration:
            self.batch_gen = batch_loader(self.ttset_training, self.batch_size)
            self.current_batch, self.current_labels = next(self.batch_gen)
        return self.current_batch[self.current_video][self.current_index]

    def step(self, action):
        reward = 0
        done = False
        info = {}
        
        # Check if the action is correct
        if action == self.current_labels[self.current_video][self.current_index]:
            reward = 1
        else:
            reward = -1
        
        self.current_index += 1
        
        if self.current_index >= len(self.current_batch[self.current_video]):
            self.current_video += 1
            self.current_index = 0
            if self.current_video >= len(self.current_batch):
                done = True
        
        next_state = self.current_batch[self.current_video][self.current_index] if not done else np.zeros((3, 60, 230, 230))
        
        return next_state, reward, done, info

    def render(self, mode='human'):
        pass

# CNN Model
class CNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*30*115*115, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.max_pool3d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.max_pool3d(x, 2)
        x = x.view(-1, 64*30*115*115)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

# Prepare data
video_frames = [frames for frames,_ in TTset_training]
classifications = [labels for _, labels in TTset_training]

# Create environment
batch_size = 5  # Adjust based on available memory
env = VideoClassificationEnv(video_frames, batch_size)

# Wrap the environment
env = make_vec_env(lambda: env, n_envs=4)

# Define the policy network
policy_kwargs = dict(
    features_extractor_class=CNNModel,
    features_extractor_kwargs=dict(num_classes=20),
)

# Instantiate the PPO agent
model = PPO('CnnPolicy', env, policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs, verbose=1)

# Training with progress bar
total_timesteps = 10000
with tqdm(total=total_timesteps) as pbar:
    for _ in range(0, total_timesteps, 2048):
        model.learn(total_timesteps=2048, reset_num_timesteps=False)
        pbar.update(2048)

# Save the model
model.save("video_classification_model")


I'm using the above code for making an RL model that will be able to classify video clips. The load_TTset function returns dataloader objects, which is derived from a previous code. I'm storing the video frames in the video_frames list, and their respective classificaiton in the classifications list. There are 20 unique classifications. The video_frames list has dimensions 129x15x(3x60x230x230), and the classifications list has dimensions 129x15. As evident, one element of dimensions 3x60x230x230 is 3 sets of randomly selected 60 frames of dimensions 230x230.
The problem I'm facing, is this matrix is too large. I'm getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/prototype2.py", line 120, in <module>
    model = PPO('CnnPolicy', env, policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs, verbose=1)
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\ppo\ppo.py", line 171, in __init__
    self._setup_model()
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\ppo\ppo.py", line 174, in _setup_model
    super()._setup_model()
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\on_policy_algorithm.py", line 124, in _setup_model
    self.rollout_buffer = self.rollout_buffer_class(
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\buffers.py", line 388, in __init__
    self.reset()
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\buffers.py", line 391, in reset
    self.observations = np.zeros((self.buffer_size, self.n_envs, *self.obs_shape), dtype=np.float32)
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 291. GiB for an array with shape (2048, 4, 3, 60, 230, 230) and data type float32

I tried making a batch loader, which returns batches of 5, but still no luck. It's not possible for me to install a RAM of this size, hence I require some pointers.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.
After running the initial code, I got a MemoryError, as the file was too large to handle. I tried making a batch loader, which returns batches of 5, but still no luck. It's not possible for me to install a RAM of this size, hence I require some pointers.

You need to reduce the observation space shape or get more RAM or use a different algorithm.

why don't you use cloud base resources like colab?

@NargesGhanbari Colab only has 12 gb of RAM I believe, and I can't afford a paid version right now.

@Dr.Snoopy could you give me some pointers?
